# Signalling a relation

Tags: optimization, profit-maximization, inequality, signaling, difference-equations

I have a very basic, trivial question to ask. (I apologise if it is not a worthy problem)

I have been trying to formulate an international Economics model where a larger country is trying to signal a relation to two countries, like one is better than the other. So, basically smaller Country A produces output a and smaller Country B produces output b (and output is only observable to larger country L). So, L signals a>b through stake s. L doesn't want to tell the exact amount by which the output differs (because that would defeat the whole purpose as low output producing firm encourages on this unknown gap to try to lower export price to remain partner with L)... So it can't signal a-b or a/b. But if it only signals s(a>b)... How will I solve difference equation where L has to decide whether to signal true a, b or lie. I can derivate with respect to s but when I'll substitute truth telling value, I can't do it because how can you substitute a relation.

How to go about it? Any papers, suggestions would work.

Thanks in advance